# JPA + EJB + JSF: how can design complicated query

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I am using netbean 6.8 btw.
Let say that I have 4 different tables: `Company`, `Facility`, `Project`, and `Document`. So the relationship is this. A company can have multiple facilities. A facility can have multiple projects, and a project can have multiple documents.

`Company`:
+companyNum: PK
+facilityNum: FK

`Facility`:
+facilityNum: PK
+projectNum: FK

`Project`:
+projectNum: PK
+drawingNum: FK

So when I create `Entity Class From Database` in netbean 6.8, I have 4 entity classes that named after the above 4 tables. So if I want to see all the `Document` in the database, then it is easy. In my `SessionBean`, I would do this:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
List<Document> documents = em.createNamedQuery("Document.findAll").getResultList();
```

However, that is not all what I need. Let say that I want to know all the `Document` from a particular `Company`, or all the `Document` from a particular `Project` from a particular `Facility` from a particular `Company`. I am very new to JPA + EJB + JSF as a whole. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Your relationships should be declared using `@ManyToOne` (e.g. in `Document` on `projects` collection) and then use `inner join` in JPA queries, e.g. selecting all document for given project:

```
select d from Document d inner join d.projects p where p.id = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the [Chapter 27 - The Java Persistence Query Language](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html) from The Java EE Tutorials is a decent introduction and will help you to get started with JPQL. This is actually where you should start.